# access vba replace vblf's with vbcrlf's

Tags: ms-access, replace, vba

Lets say for example my table name is    "thistablelf"  and the column where I want to replace all the vblf occurances is  called   "vblftovbcrlf".

How do I replace all occurances of vblf's to vbcrlf's?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the vb* constants dont work in Access SQL so how about;

```
UPDATE thistablelf 
  SET vblftovbcrlf = replace([vblftovbcrlf],Chr(13),Chr(13) & Chr(10));
```